# Write a function that prints the number of days with sunshine >= 6 hours

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have a questions for some homework, that I am really struggling with.

I need to write a function in python that prints the number of days with at least six hours of sunshine durations, given a large csv-file (picture of the first 25 lines attached).
I am not sure how to tell the function, that it should only search in a given column (the column containing sunshine duration-information, named sdk). However, I have tried the following code, but can't even run it, since it says "invalid syntax" at my if-statement (which I don't understand why it does)

```
def sunshine(file):
    data = np.genfromtxt('file', delimiter=",")
    count=0
    for value in data [data[:,9]: #because sdk=9th column
        if value>=6:
            count+=1
    print(count)
```

[image: Picture of dataset]

Comment: `for value in data[:, 9]`

Comment: Can you share the entire error message?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the pandas library for this. Read the CSV into a data frame, then filter it based on the SDK value and get the length of the data frame. Since you said this is a homework assignment, im not going to do all the work for you, but here is some pseudocode to get you started:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv(r'Path To File')
df1 = df.loc[df['column_name'] > some_value]
total_number = len(df1)
```